# How to use strtolower() in a query in PHP

Tags: php, lowercase

In a database I have this field: "**TeST**". I don’t know where the upper case characters are. I just want to [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) them and do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE strtolower(field) = strtolower($var)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Using PDO and assuming MySQL

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(`field`) = ?');
$stmt->execute(array(strtolower($var)));
```

Answer (score 10):

In MySQL, the function is called [`LOWER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) Then again, you can just use a case-insensitive collation on the field or in the query, and it will match regardless of case, which seems the better option.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE LOWER(`field_name`)='" . strtolower($_var) . "'";
```

Or use:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE LCASE(`field_name`)='" . strtolower($_var) . "'";
```

Both functions works same.

Answer (score 5):

The `LOWER` function in MySQL can be used to convert a field value to lower case.

For example:

```
"select * from table_name where LOWER(email) = ?";
```